# Re-rendering a Component When an Object Changes

Tags: reactjs

I want to rerender my component if nested object has been changed:

```
   announcement.attachments <-- THIS HAS CHANGED AND COMPONENT SHOULD BE RERENDERED
```

```
export const AttachmentsTab = () => {
    // const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState();
    const { announcement } = useAnnouncement(); // from context, nested object attachments is changed
    const noAttachments =
        !announcement.attachments?.carrier &&
        !announcement.attachments?.shipper;
    // setAttachments({ ...announcement.attachments });
    const attachments = { ...announcement.attachments }; // I tried with creating a copy
    console.log('attachments', attachments);

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {noAttachments ? (
                <EmptyContent
                    title={labels.noAtt}
                    message={labels.noAttDescr}
                />
            ) : (
                <Rows>
                        <>
                            <Items
                                attachments={announcement.attachments?.shipper}
                            />

                            <Items
                                attachments={announcement.attachments?.carrier}
                            />
                        </>
```

How to do that? Currently this component is rerender only when there is change in object `noAttachments`

Answer (score 0):

Always when we say *'re-render when a variable change'*, we should directly think of `useEffect()`;

You can use the `useEffect()` hook to observe changes in the `announcement.attachments` object and trigger a re-render of your component.

```js
    const noAttachments =
        !announcement.attachments?.carrier &&
        !announcement.attachments?.shipper;

    // memoize the attachments object to prevent unnecessary re-renders
    const memoizedAttachments = useMemo(() => {
        return { ...announcement.attachments };
    }, [announcement.attachments]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // this code will execute whenever memoizedAttachments changes
        console.log('Attachments have changed:', memoizedAttachments);
    }, [memoizedAttachments]);
```

Read more about [useMemo()](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usememo.asp) and [useEffect()](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp)

Comment: OK but what next? Changing <Items
                                attachments={announcement.attachments?.shipper}
                            /> into <Items
                                attachments={memoizedAttachments?.shipper}
                            /> changed nothing - component is not rerendered and I can't use useState inside useEffect

Comment: @Matley, does the `Attachments have changed` shows in your console when you want to re-render ?

Comment: yes.. For now I used key prop in <Wrapper key={key}>Component will not be rendered many times so performance will not decrease